# JQuery: Fancybox opens image in tab - ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox to create a gallery on my website - Asp.Net MVC

I've added all the libraries, however, the images seem to load up in a new tab instead of working like pops with the arrows on the side.

Here is what I have in the view:

```
  @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Gallery";

  }

 <head>

<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<link href="../../Content/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" 
 type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script>

<link href="../../Content/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" 
 type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.fancybox-media.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script>

 </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
        });
    });
   </script>
```

Here is are some of the images I am trying to add:

```
<body>
<br />
<div class="bodyText">

    <center>

        <h1>Gallery</h1>

        <p>Pictures taken by me in Agadir (Morocco), Dubai (UAE) and Sylhet (Bangladesh)</p>
        <br /><br />
    </center>

    <!--inserting the images and adding descriptions-->
    <center>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="../../Content/images/agadir.jpg" title="Marina"><img src="../../Content/images/rsz_agadir.jpg" style='border:2px solid #ffffff' alt="" hspace="5" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="../../Content/images/agadirmountain.jpg" title="Atlas Mountains trip"><img src="../../Content/images/rsz_agadirmountain.jpg" style='border:2px solid #ffffff' alt="" hspace="5" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="../../Content/images/agadirsunset.jpg" title="Sunset in Agadir"><img src="../../Content/images/rsz_agadirsunset.jpg" style='border:2px solid #ffffff' alt="" hspace="5" /></a>
```

I've added a fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MYo1WG

Comment: See if adding  data-fancybox-group="gallery" to your links work

Comment: I'm sorry for coming across as incompetent, but where shall I add this?

Comment: hah! no worries! I included the answer below. I replaced ref="gallery" with it, but if you want to add ref="gallery" back, you can.

Comment: You should create a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) which replicates the functionality that is causing you dramas so that we can provide an accurate answer for your specific case. Also, are there any errors getting thrown?

Comment: @Zze No errors are getting thrown. It's supposed to display larger images of the thumbnails in a popup window and have arrows which allow me to scroll through them. Instead, it opens the larger in the tab. Here is the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MYo1WG

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YGj6rZ I took all your code, and it let the js and the css load up. If you're clicking on the link, and it redirects to the jpg, then you loaded your js incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check developer tools, you have JS error on your page -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Fix this and it should work. The other message should give you a clue:

`'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: It's saying "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function". I've tried adding a noConflict but still getting the error

Comment: I had another look and I've solved it!           it was $(document).ready(function() {                             I changed it         $(document).ready(function($) { and now it is working perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="../../Content/images/agadir.jpg" title="Marina"><img src="../../Content/images/rsz_agadir.jpg" style='border:2px solid #ffffff' alt="" hspace="5" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="../../Content/images/agadirmountain.jpg" title="Atlas Mountains trip"><img src="../../Content/images/rsz_agadirmountain.jpg" style='border:2px solid #ffffff' alt="" hspace="5" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="../../Content/images/agadirsunset.jpg" title="Sunset in Agadir"><img src="../../Content/images/rsz_agadirsunset.jpg" style='border:2px solid #ffffff' alt="" hspace="5" /></a>
```

data-fancybox-group is an attribute that the fancybox plugin would you to allow you to traverse through the gallery, like a carousel.

Edit:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/YGj6rZ

In your fiddle, I saw nothing really wrong, I moved the script from between head and body tag, and placed it in the head tag. And then I just loaded the js and css scripts from fancy box. It went from opening a tab to working with the plugin. There must have been something wrong with the way you're loading your script and css files.

Comment: hmm seems to work on my end, what version of fancybox are you using? Are you using fancybox 3? or fancybox 2?

Comment: I'm using Fancybox 2.1.5